# Ghc's profiling and code coverage options conflict?

Tags: haskell, ghc

For GHC, if I add the `-fhpc` option while the `-prof -fprof-auto` options are enabled, GHC does not add any cost centers to the code, and the profiling report shows only CAFs. However, if I remove `-fhpc` profiling works fine. Is there a reason for this? Is there a way to enable both of these features?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no deep reason behind this - the simple truth of the matter is that GHC's "Coverage" pass is only run once (at maximum), and only ever generates one kind of annotation.

I think at this point it would mainly be a question of somebody putting in a bit of time to implement a fix and properly check that mixtures of annotations don't cause bad side-effects. Opening a [GHC ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/newticket) for this particular issue might be a good idea - especially if you have a good use-case.